# separating vector fields

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a perl script..I am new to perl. Here is my code

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = $ARGV[0] ;
my $file2 = 'output.txt';

open FH, $file or die $!;
open FHH, "> $file2" or die $!;

while(<FH>) {
    if(/SIB_DBG/) {
        my $val = $_;
        if($val = /TTRB:([\da-f]+)/) {
            print "$1 \n";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a line of an input file

```
Aug 31 15:25:53 usb3 kernel: [   78.813721] SIB_DBG TTRB:00000000 00000000 00000000 00001021, PTR: ffff88005ff8b850
```

I am able to separate first field of 8 byte right after `TTRB`. But how to separate the three fields after that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    if($val =~ /TTRB:([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)/)
    {
        print "$1 $2 $3 $4\n";
    }
```

$1 contains the first 8 bytes
$2 contains the second 8 bytes and so on

Comment: Yeah it worked..But if further I want to convert each chunk of 8byte data to binary and store it to another variable..so what should I do..I tried packing-unpacking on $1,$2 ..but it didn't work..and yeah does $1 ,$2 recognize that it is having hex data??

Comment: @IshitaShah ask a new question for that. No $1 is only a string it is no knowledgof hex data.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is trivial, as repeating the regex will extract further data from the string. I have some other points to share, though.

- You should always use three argument version of `open`, with explicit mode, and use lexical file handles. E.g.: `open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!`
- You do not need to explicitly open the file, you can use the diamond operator, which will read the input automatically. This is the idiomatic way to do it in Perl. E.g. `while (<>) { ... }`. On the command line, this is what the `-n` and `-p` switches do.
- Similarly, instead of opening an output file, just print to stdout and redirect the output in the terminal. E.g. `perl foo.pl input.txt > output.txt`.

Also note this part of your code:

```
    if($val = /TTRB:([\da-f]+)/) {
```

Here you are using the assignment operator `=`, when you probably intended to use the binding operator `=~`. The result is that it is not the content of `$val` that is checked, but the content of `$_`. Then the return value of that check is assigned to `$val`. It is the same as writing

```
    if($val = $_ =~  /TTRB:([\da-f]+)/) {
```

Because a regex match without a binding operator always defaults to checking `$_`.

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<>) {
    if (/SIB_DBG/) {
        if (/TTRB:((?:[\da-f]+\s*)+)/) {
            print "$1 \n";
        }
    }
}
```

This will simply match repeated sequences of alphanumerics and print them. You should note that this can be simplified quite a lot, down to the rudimentary one-liner:

```
perl -nle 'print /SIB_DBG\s+TTRB:((?:[\da-f]+\s*)+)/' input.txt > output.txt
```

The match from the regex will be returned to `print`, which prints it directly, and the `-l` switch will add a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl global regex matches (with the `/g` modifier) in scalar context. That makes the match find just the *next* occurrence of the pattern, so you can work through a string step by step

This program first checks that it can find `TTRB:` in the string, and skips it if not. But when it does find the string it leaves an internal pointer specific to that string set right after `TTRB:` so that the next global match will start looking from there

Then it finds all occurrences of eight hex digits, possibly followed by some white space. The `\G` anchor forces each match to start exactly where the previous one ended, so when it reaches `00001021` which is followed by a comma, the next search will fail because the pattern requires that the next eight digits start where the comma is

I've used `Data::Dump` only to display the contents of `@data` after the operation

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    next unless /TTRB:/g;

    my @data = /\G(\p{hex}{8})\s*/g;
    dd \@data;
}

__DATA__
Aug 31 15:25:53 usb3 kernel: [   78.813721] SIB_DBG TTRB:00000000 00000000 00000000 00001021, PTR: ffff88005ff8b850
```

#### output

```
["00000000", "00000000", "00000000", "00001021"]
```